# Multi file upload with multi inputs

Tags: php, html

My script can be used for multiple file uploads from 1 input only. Users select files from just one input. But I want to use multi file upload with multi file inputs. My script is;

html

```
<form id="imageuploadust" action="./uploadres.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<input class="uploaded" type="file" value="Ekle" name="item_file[]" id="fileust1" accept="image/*" size="70" multiple>

</form>
```

PHP

```
if(count($_FILES["item_file"]['name'])>0)
 { 

 $GLOBALS['msg'] = ""; //initiate the global message
  for($j=0; $j < count($_FILES["item_file"]['name']); $j++)
 {

$ben = time();
$duz = rand(0,99);
$benduz = "$ben$duz.jpg";

   $path = 'bayan/'.$benduz; //generate the destination path
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["item_file"]['tmp_name']["$j"],$path)) 
{

echo "success";

   }

   }
```

Which approach should I do to multi file upload from multi inputs ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For **file upload** purpose i would **recommand** the plugin [JQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) which have much **functionnalities**.

- Multi upload support
- Css/Html handle
- No refresh of the page (Dynamic)
- Progress bar (upload)
- Error handle
- Cancel upload possibility